# How can I install PHP 5.6 (instead of 5.4)?

Tags: raspbian, apt, php

I'm actually stuck with a little problem.
I want to use Laravel on my pi but it requires at least PHP 5.5.9.

But actually, the latest version of PHP that I am able to install (via the official repository) is the 5.4

How can I upgrade to 5.6 (or 5.5.9) ?

Comment: Looks like you will have to build it from source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the steps you can follow.

1. Grab latest source from this site. (http://php.net/downloads.php) Choose your nearest mirror.
   For example, I did "wget [https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.6.10.tar.bz2"](https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.6.10.tar.bz2%22)
2. Unpack it:
   `tar -xvjf php-5.6.10.tar.bz2`
3. `cd php-5.6.10`
4. `./configure`
5. `make -j4` (if you're compiling it on Rpi 2) else just `make`
6. `sudo make install`
7. Test it by firing `php -v`

It should be now upgraded to 5.6

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for you post but for the very first time I'm not able to install it with this method.
I don't know why but I think I've got a bug with the ./configure, it seems it does not work correctly because I am not able to use "make" (makefile is not created).

[Log file here](http://pastebin.com/juhtKL3d)

Comment: You will have to install related dependencies. See the error. Pi is missing libxml2. To install that, "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libxml2". Try configuring again. You may face other dependencies issues. You will have to install each on using "sudo apt-get install" before you can proceed with make. Hope it helps.

Comment: When I try to install libxml2, it says that it's already installed ... How is it possible ?

Comment: Try : sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev

Comment: Thank you very much it worked well and I was able to execute make & then install ;)

Comment: One more question, I think I've got a little problem with nginx.
Actually, php 5.4 is still used on my website but when I use php -v it tells me that php 5.6 is running, maybe a config file to edit ?
http://i.imgur.com/xt1Zhqy.png

Comment: Locate old php.ini file by "sudo find / -name php.ini" and copy the new one from php-5.6 directory by "sudo cp php.ini-production  /path/to/php.ini" That should do, I guess.

Comment: https://downloads.php.net/~ab/

Comment: Did anyone manage to check whether the compile includes php5-mbstring?

Comment: @brianlmerritt: You should check the other answer.

Comment: I have edited that answer, awaiting peer review.  The correct way to get php_mbstring on any debian based OS is `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

Comment: @Germain67 I am having the same issue that php -v tells me the 5.6 version but apache2 still using the old php5.4. I did exactly you suggested that copied the php.ini-production file to the /etc/php5/apache2/ folder to replace the old one and then restarted apache2 but still showing the old php5.4. Can some help me pointing out what maybe I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @Humayun Have you tried to rename "php.ini-production" to "php.ini" ?
Then try to restart apache2, hope it will do the trick ;)

Answer (score 5):

At the time of this writing (november 2015), raspbian is built on Debian Jessie. The installable PHP version is in the 5.6 branch.

However, for Laravel projects you will need a number of PHP extensions. Most of these are available in the Raspbian repositories (or out of the box), but the php_mbstring extension cannot be loaded via apt-get.

Instead, to get php5_mbstring run `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` which includes it (reference comments in http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php)