# Install PHP 5.6 on Raspbian version 2015-5-5

Tags: php

This may be a stupid question : I followed the instructions of [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32743/how-can-i-install-php-5-6-instead-of-5-4) on Raspbian and a Raspberry Pi 2, and after 20 min it was still running the `make -j4`. I stopped it because it was heating too much (20 min at 100% processor ...). Is it normal ? Should I wait longer ?
(In the terminal it displays lots of things like in an usual `make`)

Comment: And what does it show on terminal ? Is it stuck at something ?

Comment: I added it in the post.

Comment: I would say wait for some more. If it's processing. I remember it took fair amount of time on Rpi 2. If it's not stuck, let it be.

Comment: I'm currently trying [this](http://snippets.khromov.se/php-5-5-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi/) (because I only need PHP 5.5) and if it does not work I'll retry the `make` with a fan to cool the Pi. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there is output and it is not obviously hung, it is working.  In theory a build could go into an infinite loop but it seems very unlikely -- usually they just crap out.

A language interpreter is a complex piece of business.  There are also limitations to the amount of work that can actually be done in parallel using `-j`.  It will often be that only one or two cores are actually working 100%, and the Pi 2's cores are small.

To summarize, I'm not surprised at all that building PHP on a Pi 2 takes *at least* 20 minutes.  If you'd said it was done in 15, I'd be impressed.  Not so long ago, when everything was single core and < 1 Ghz, building stuff like this could take hours.  Even *overnight*.  Enjoy waking up to `ERROR: in foobar.c :P`...

Fortunately [dastaan's comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33640/install-php-5-6-on-raspbian-version-2015-5-5#comment43850_33640) implies you won't have to wait that long.

Comment: +1 Also, worth mentioning: Processors are allowed to get hot; what we consider too hot (by feel) is usually well within the device's tolerance range.  @math45 doesn't have anything to worry about there.

Comment: Good point, I sort of skimmed passed that in the question.  The pi's processors won't overheat running at 100% unless you overclock them (or you have a really hot environment).

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with compiling php 5.6.16 with Wheezy, but 5.6.14 did compile after half an hour or so.

Remember that Raspbian Jesse and Jesse Lite both come with PHP5.6 out of the box. If you are using Laravel don't forget to apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 which includes the crucial php5_mbstring